# SQL conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to run some update scripts on my database and I am getting the following error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UPSELL_DT_AMRNO_AFMKTG_REF". The conflict occurred in database "ECOMVER", table "dbo.AFFILIATE_MKTG_REF", column 'AMRNO'.

I am running the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UPSELL_DATA]  WITH CHECK ADD 
        CONSTRAINT [FK_UPSELL_DT_AMRNO_AFMKTG_REF] FOREIGN KEY
        (
          [AMRNO]
        ) REFERENCES [dbo].[AFFILIATE_MKTG_REF] (
          [AMRNO]
        )
GO
```

AMRNO is a PK in table AFFILIATE_MKTG_REF.

Also, I tried to create the foreign key relation using the modify table option in SQL Management studio and I got the same error. I am not sure what I should be looking for?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By adding WITH NOCHECK I was able to create the FK relation. This does not seem like the right thing to do...

Comment: This will basically make the constraint "untrusted" (http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1539) - basically, this is NOT checking to ensure the constraint is valid for data that already exists in the tables and will instead only check for newly inserted records.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You probably have records in your [dbo].[UPSELL_DATA] table with values in the [AMRNO] column that don't exist in the [dbo].[AFFILIATE_MKTG_REF] table, [AMRNO] column. Try a query like this to find those that don't have matching records:

```
select   *
from     [dbo].[UPSELL_DATA] u
left join [dbo].[AFFILIATE_MKTG_REF] m
on       u.AMRNO = m.AMRNO
where    m.AMRNO is null
```

Comment: Hello Chad,

Thanks for the response. Yes, there are three records that return from your query.  Do these records need to be removed before I create the FK?

Comment: Well, if you want to create a trusted constraint, you'll have to either delete them from the UPSELL_DATA table, or create associated entries in the AFFILIATE_MKTG_REF table for the given IDs. The only other option would be to keep/create an un-trusted constraint as discussed in the link above (and here http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1539).

Comment: That's correct. 5 years of SQL and I couldn't figure this one out today, where's my coffee at.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have data restricted by foreign key try to check the data on both tables before assigning a foreign key, whether there are restrictions on both the tables.