# What would be the best way to link these two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have two tables in a database, both of which are derived from official government reference tables originally supplied in spreadsheet form.

The structure of these two tables are illustrated below.

Table 1 (Species Codes)

[image]

Table 2 (Allowed presentation codes)

[image]

When I try and create a relationship between the first and the second (so as to make full use of the ability to look up values in the second table I get the following error when trying to link speciescodes.FAOCode to allowedstates.ErsSpeciesCodes).

'SpeciesCodeLookup' table saved successfully
'AllowedPresentationAndStateCodesLookup' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_AllowedPresentationAndStateCodesLookup_SpeciesCodeLookup'.
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AllowedPresentationAndStateCodesLookup_SpeciesCodeLookup". The conflict occurred in database "FishTrackerPro", table "dbo.SpeciesCodeLookup", column 'FAOCode'.

Can anyone enlighten me as to 
1) why is this error occurring
2) is there a way (by altering one or other table where such a relation might be established?

Comment: Which is the PK table and which is the FK table? From the error, it sounds like the existing data in the FK column does not exist in the PK column

Comment: @Raj Apologies, the Primary key Table is SpeciesCodes (table 1 in the question) , the Foreign key Is Allowed presentations (table 2 in the question).  Faocodes in table 1 are unique, they occur multiple times in table 2).  To the best of my knowledge thre are no ErsSpeciesCodes in table 2 that are not represented in table 1.

Comment: Please try executing `SELECT ErsSpeciesCodes FROM Allowedpresentations WHERE ErsSpeciesCodes NOT IN (SELECT Faocodes FROM SpeciesCodes` to make sure that is not the case. The error definitely means that there are some values missing

Comment: @Raj  You're quite correct, turns out that the government supplied lists are out by one record!!

Comment: Yeah and my answer was also correct all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are getting this issue because referential integrity is not met. I.e Foreign key table must not have values which does not exists in primary key table.

Check these links :

1. [Alter table conflicted with foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839309/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint/)
2. [SQL conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758987/sql-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint/)